# JSON REST Api Pagination page out of bounds or empty collection response code

Tags: json, api, rest

Looking for some best practices please...

Scenario 1: `GET: /api/v1/widgets/?page=10&per_page=5` The widgets collection only contains 10 records. So the page is out of bounds.

Scenario 2: `GET: /api/v1/widgets/` The widgets collection is currently empty.

So in both scenarios, I am looking for an appropriate status code and response.

My thoughts:

- `422 unprocessable entity` Normally used for validation, however in this case, I think it would be appropriate because the `page` requested is out-of-bounds. Particularly useful for scenario 1
- `400 bad request` Because the page is out-of-bounds: Scenario 1
- `404 Not found` Because the resource is empty: Scenario 1 & 2
- `204 No Content`Because both collections return empty data: Scenarion 1 & 2
- `200 - with data as empty array` because url is valid, but content is non-existent. Scenarios 1 & 2

Is there a current best-practice for this structure?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to return an empty collection and status code 200. In addition, you should provide hyperlinks in the response header to point clients to "correct" pages, for example the first page or the last "valid" page. For paging of collection resources, the server should always respond with hyperlinks to previous and next pages.

Comment: Many thanks. Aware of setting headers to show total resources, pages, current page etc... I was just looking for the best practice http response code. You suggest 200 with empty array in both scenarios?

Comment: Yes. In the second scenario, it's a 200 because the request was correct and it's just the collection that is empty. In the first scenario, it must not be a 404, because the collection resource does exist (only the requested page does not), and not a 400, because the client did not make a syntax error (it's more a semantic error to send wrong page numbers). It can't be a 422, because you don't send a request body, compare [this](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4918#page-7). Status 204 should be sent if the server "does not need to return an entity-body" but may send updated meta-information.